# Swift PureMVC : Does not conform to NSObjectProtocol

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, puremvc

I want to manage all location code in one of my Proxy classes. As the class is built from scratch and not built on a `UIView` or similar class that inherits `NSObjectProtocol`, it throws an error 'Does not conform to protocol `NSObjectProtocol` when I am trying to add `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.

```
class GeoProxy : Proxy, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
   var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

   override class var NAME: String { return "GeoProxy" }
}
```

Any idea, how I get the class to conform without adding all `NSObjectProtocol` functions?

Answer (score 13):

Easier way is making `Proxy` class inherit from `NSObject`:

```
class Proxy: NSObject {
}
```

Then, all subclasses will conform to `NSObjectProtocol`. In addition, these classes will be compatible with Objective-C code.

Comment: I need Swift. But okay. Cool did it on the Notifier class level.

Comment: import Foundation

public class Notifier : NSObject, INotifier {

Answer (score 5):

It's best to put `CLLocationManagerDelegate` related code in a `viewComponent` (`UIViewController`) and handle things from there, UIViewController is already inherited from `NSObject` so there's no need to change core actors of PureMVC (`Notifier` in this case).

**Another option** is to create an independent class to manage location related activities, for instance instantiate a Mediator `LocationMediator` instantiating `class Location: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate` as it's viewComponent and setting itself as a delegate via `ILocation` protocol.

`LocationMediator` would listen to any events from it's viewComponent via `ILocation` delegate and it would then send a notification that other interested actors can respond to.

**Hardware related activity belongs to View**

Any hardware related activity for instance Camera, GPS, Accelerometer, Gyroscope and non-hardware elements like Router in a browser typically generate events and belong to view tier of the MVC paradigm and should be handled inside a view component. Any triggered events within viewComponents are then handled by it's mediator if it needs to communicate to the other parts of the system. `Proxy` is best suited for web services or persistence.